# Installing Windows 7 onto a 2017 MacBook Air without MacOS

Tags: windows-7, mac, macbook

As the title says, I am trying to install Windows 7 onto a 2017 MacBook Air without using MacOS or bootcamp. I have been imaging my Windows 7 ISO onto a thumb drive, but the drive will either not show up in the boot-manager or will not do anything when booted. I have installed other operating systems onto the MacBook without any issues, such as various distributions of Linux. Is there any way to install Windows 7 onto my MacBook?

Answer (score 0):

These is no practical way to install Windows 7 onto your MacBook.

Windows 7 was installed on older Macs to BIOS boot. The Windows drivers provided by Apple for your Mac assume Windows will be installed to UEFI boot. Furthermore by 2017, Apple no longer included a BIOS in the firmware of any Mac model being produced. Therefore, if you did use Boot Camp, you still would not be able to install Windows 7 on your Mac.

You should be able to install Windows 7 as a virtual machine where macOS would be the host. Both VirtualBox and VMware Player are free products when used for personal purposes.